# Bottom menu bar with access to cmd prompt and python console in Pycharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 5 for Python, and I don't seem to get the following menu with links to the cmd prompt, Python console and version control in the computers I have installed the program. However, I can't find the Settings that deploy this useful menu at the bottom of the screen. So, the question is, How can I deploy (and close) this menu bar:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to include the lower toolbar from menu:
View -> Tool Buttons

[image]

Secondly, you will have the bottom button console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the left bottom icon to show / hide it - see the green arrow:

[image]
You may also select from the mini menu, which pops-up if you hover over it.